# Generally-Accepted Bean Validation Methods

Tags: java, apache, validation, aop, javabeans

So I've been reading up on the (incubating) Apache Bean Validation project and it seems like pretty cool stuff. It looks like it's predicated on decorating fields with annotations called **constraints** and by implementing `Validator` interfaces, manifesting itself, sort of, like so:

```
public class Employee
{
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max=50)
    private String email;

    // etc...
}
```

I know there are other annotation processors out there that could allow you to emulate this functionality yourself, or perhaps using other frameworks, such as the AOP-based Guice IoC framework from Google.

Has anyboody here ever experimented with all of these frameworks? Care to weigh-in with performance, pitfall or caveat-type recommendations. This Bean Validation project looks like something I'd really like to dive in to, but it would be an expensive (timme-wise) lesson to learn if it turns out that there are better, more generally-accepted ways of performing validation of beans/POJOs and the likes with minimal redundancy.

Thanks for any comments or suggestions here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd jump in, although I might use Hibernate Validator instead.

Both Apache Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator are based on the JSR303 so are industry standards.

Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of the standard. http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Either way if you stick to a JSR standard then you should be able to switch to different implementations if you need to later.